# GA Limit of 500 hits per session - workarounds & awareness?

Tags: google-analytics, javascript, google-tag-manager, debug

We're currently walking the fine line between gathering as much data about the user journey and interaction with the site - and also being aware of our 500 or bust limit that GA analytics imposes on us.

Does anybody know of an approach that we can discover within GA - after the ceiling of 500 hits in one session has been reached - maybe a metric or dimension we can interrogate within the GA report?

Is there anyway to debug within client side JavaScript - the current hit counter - it must be available somewhere?  What would be amazing is a way to keep a track of this count number - and then throttle back less essential GA events via GTM.

Comment: Does this limit exist for the paid version of GA too?

Comment: Hi Sandy - yes it does.  Apparently it is part of the Universal Analytics tracking client side code - so I'd like to dig into it to understand how we can keep a track of what the remaining hits are.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that. Sorry I can't help you here.

Comment: I'd think that you would either have to have very long sessions or send excessive numbers of events to hit a 500 per user limit.    Even if sound 10 events per page, your users could view 50 pages before hitting the limit.

Comment: Stephen - the metrics we have for this particular site do indeed need such a long line of hits.  Does anybody know how to track the counter?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about a server site solution, but I can give some tips how to measure effectively how to keep an eye on this. Since Google Analytics already gives you the option to use “Hits” as a metric you only need a dimension about the session to pair up with. We did this by an example of Simo Ahava (https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/improve-data-collection-with-four-custom-dimensions/). Creating a custom dimension containing a unique ID for a session (session scope) does enable you to see how many hits there are per session. You will even get a better overview of what happens, when and by whom if you install all 4 of the custom dimensions suggested by Simo.

You then can create a powerful custom report to keep track of limits.

Answer (score 1):

My latest solution was to capitalize on cookie counter which was trigger as "Cleanup Tag" after heavy hit tags such as Product Impressions, Review Impressions ... etc. There was a limit set up for 350 hits so the session hit count wouldn´t be overloaded.

Code used follows:

```
<script>
  (function() {
// read the cookie
var daCounter = {{COOKIE.viewcount}};
// if empty
if (typeof daCounter === "undefined") {
// start counting
daCounter = 1;
} else {
// otherwise add 1
daCounter++;
}

// than crate a cookie
setSessionCookie("DA-VC", daCounter);

})();

//function to set a cookie
function setSessionCookie(name, value) {
var cookie = name + "=" + value + "; path=/; domain=." + location.hostname.replace(/^www\./i, "");
 // set it
document.cookie = cookie;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Report showing sessions that are hitting the limit.]

This is only possible if you have set a custom dimension as per Simo's recommendation above.